# JPQL where in array query

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, jpql

I'm trying to update every record for which I have the id in my arraylist but I'm getting this error:

```
IllegalStateException occured : org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update models.UserOnline uo SET currentRoom_id = :roomid where uo.id IN (:list)]
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
    Query update_query = JPA.em().createQuery("update UserOnline uo SET currentRoom_id = :roomid where uo.id IN (:list)");
    update_query.setParameter("roomid", null);
    update_query.setParameter("list", idlist);

    List<UserOnline> actual = update_query.getResultList();
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try with `update_query.executeUpdate();`

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Like Gonzalo already said, you'd have to use **executeUpdate**().

This is **because you're actually MODIFYing data** .

You **only use getResultList() or getSingleResult() if you want to GET data** out of the database.

a little helper:
use **executeUpdate**() if your query has the form

```
UPDATE ... SET .. WHERE ..
or
DELETE ... WHERE ...
```

use **getResultList**() or **getSingleResult**() if the query looks like

```
SELECT ... FROM xxx WHERE ... 
or just
FROM xxx WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we use Spring Repositories (CrudRepository or any of its type), and if we have a method declaration with an update Query
That is,

@Query("update employee e set e.name= :name where e.id = :id")
int updateEmployee(@Param("name") String name, @Param("id") Long id);

Then we will get the related Spring Exception org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations

Just add @Modifying annotation on the method and it will be fine.